# Where is the best place to sit on an airplane?

Tags: safety

I'm going on a flight soon and I am wondering where the best place to sit is as I want to be sure that if anything happens, I would want the seat to be convenient for most situations.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Comment: Well, for a community of aviation enthusiasts, the *best seat* is one with a view out the front. But, presumably you're talking about a passenger flight.

Comment: The most likely thing to "happen" is you requiring to go to the toilet. In this case you'd want to be in an isle seat not too far away from the lavatory :)

Comment: @Zeus I would consider aspects such as: Safety and view outside other than just the lavatory

Comment: Nothing is going to happen.  The best seat on the plane is the front left one, but its reserved for the Captain.

Comment: I'm more interested in the best seat IN the plane...

Comment: @abelenky: But in my plane, I AM the captain :-)  And I think questions like this would be better suited to the Travel site.